# How to clean memory with the memory tool application?

Tags: android

Now there are some memory mananger tool apps that can clean system memory in google market. How does them work? I think they only can invoke System.gc(). Because application must get root permission to stop other services and processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my taskmaneger source:
http://code.google.com/p/my-test-project-lion/
The basic method is  `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcess`

```
    public void killSelf(Context context) {
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            am.killBackgroundProcesses(getPackageName());

            if (mServiceList != null) {
                    for (RunningServiceInfo service : mServiceList) {
                            context.stopService(new Intent().setComponent(service.service));
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: hi, does my application can refuse to be killed? Because this is not a system behavior.

Comment: ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcess will try to kill the background process. System will decide whether it will be killed. Your application cannot be refused to be killed,it is a system behavior. But if your activity is Foreground process will be not killed. You can see the process level here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle